# Wordpress translator plugin: Google Webmaster's Tools shows hundreds of 404 not found errors. How to clean the mess?

Tags: translation

I had Global Translator Wordpress plugin. It littered Google Search index with thousands of translated urls. Couple of months ago I removed the plugin and also the cached pages on the server.

But Google Index still has the translated web pages indexed and shows 404 errors in Web Master tools. I tried fixing the issue with `robots.txt` by blocking all the translated pages from index, but it's taking a long time to get it fixed. Can someone suggest me the better way to get all those indexed pages out of Google Index?

Comment: All errors are 404?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is actually on their website:

Put a rewrite rule like this on your .htaccess:
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(it|ko|zh-CN|zh-TW|pt|en|de|fr|es|ja|ar|ru|el|nl|zh|zt|no|bg|cs|hr|da|fi|hi|pl|ro|sv|ca|tl|iw|id|lv|lt|sr|sk|sl|uk|vi|sq|et|gl|mt|th|tr|hu|be|ga|is|mk|ms|fa)/(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$2

Answer (score 0):

Send a 410 status header for those resources:

.htaccess or httpd.config:

```
# adjust the query string to your URIs
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^translated
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=410]
```